# Stroboscopic effect

Tags: classical-mechanics, optics, vision

Can you explain why exactly when I see the rotating blades of a fan or helicopter, there are dark patches and the patches start rotating slowly and even start moving in the reverse direction when seen in a camera?

Comment: Does this help? <https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect>

Comment: Yes. It does.@CharlesTucker3